# Add/remove classes not working as expected

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I have a list of buttons on my page. I want to be able to click on a button and it will turn red while other buttons remains in the same color. I try to use jQuery's `removeClass()` method if other buttons have a red color. That being said, only one button is allowed to have a background color of red when clicked.

Here is the Plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/pgP05rCo5VNGdlq8h8aB?p=preview

When a button is clicked, they should turn red.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Please add your code to the question; if Plunker goes down then this question becomes unanswerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use a common class on all your `button` elements:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <p><input type="submit" class="hey" value="Button1" name="btnsubmit" id="answer" style="width: 200px;" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" class="hey" value="Button2" name="btnsubmit" id="answer" style="width: 200px;" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" class="hey" value="Button3" name="btnsubmit" id="answer" style="width: 200px;" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" class="hey" value="Button4" name="btnsubmit" id="answer" style="width: 200px;" /></p>
</div>
```

From there you can attach a single `click` event handler to cater for all of those elements. You just need to call `removeClass()` on all of them and `addClass()` on the instance that raised the event, like this:

```
$('.hey').click(function(){
    $('.hey').removeClass('red');
    $(this).addClass('red');
});
```

[**Updated plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/kkNYUr5SFKnCYTcaUlhP?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing `.red` from all buttons first, and then applying it only to the one that has been clicked.

```
// Code goes here
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.hey, .hey2, .hey3, .hey4').click(function(){
   $('.hey, .hey2, .hey3, .hey4').removeClass('red'); //Remove all classes red
   $(this).addClass('red'); // Add it only on one button.
  }); 
});
```

[Demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DxpZtRixpl9yNY4k3CeU?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

I saw two errors in your code (script.js) :

```
if(!$('.hey2').hasClass('red')){
    $("hey2").removeClass('red');
  }
```

First of all, you add a "!" in the if condition, which shouldn't be there. And also, you forgot the "." for `hey2`'s class. Here is the correction, and it worked for me :

```
if($('.hey2').hasClass('red')){
    $(".hey2").removeClass('red');
  }
```

This is just the solution to your particular problem. In practice, I think there are better ways to approach your problem. Look at the other answers (from Rory McCrossan and mbinette) for better ideas ;-)